Dynamic image of the square pyramids inscribed in a sphere that meet the criteria
Given that the side length of a regular Pyramid is $l$, and all its vertices lie on the same sphere, this sphere has a volume of $36\pi$, and $3 \leq l \leq 3\sqrt{3}$. What is the range of the volume of this tetrahedron?
A. $\left[18, \frac{81}{4}\right]$
B. $\left[\frac{27}{4}, \frac{81}{4}\right]$
C. $\left[\frac{27}{4}, \frac{64}{3}\right]$
D. $\left[18,27\right]$
Given the known conditions, the radius of the sphere can easily be determined to be R = 3. Let the side length of the square base of the pyramid be 2a, and its height be h.

R = 3;
sol = Solve[{l^2 == h^2 + (Sqrt[2] a)^2, 
    R^2 == (h - 3)^2 + (Sqrt[2] a)^2}, {a, h}][[2]]
vpyramid[l_] = 1/3  4 a^2 h /. sol
FunctionRange[{vpyramid[l], 3 <= l <= 3 Sqrt[3]}, l, y]

Using code, I have determined the range of volumes. Now, how can I display all the square pyramids that meet the known conditions in the form of an animated graph?

Pyramid or Tetrahedron?

Pyramid,regular square pyramid


c is the z coordinate of the center of the square {p1,p2,p3,p4}.

p5 is the north of the sphere.


Clear["Global`*"];
R = 3;
sol = Solve[{l^2 == h^2 + (Sqrt[2] a)^2, 
     R^2 == (h - 3)^2 + (Sqrt[2] a)^2}, {a, h}][[2]];
p5 = {0, 0, R};
c = R - h /. sol;
{p1, p2, p3, 
   p4} = {{2 a*Sqrt[2]/2, 0, c}, {0, 2 a*Sqrt[2]/2, 
     c}, {-2 a*Sqrt[2]/2, 0, c}, {0, -2 a*Sqrt[2]/2, c}} /. sol;
circle = {0, 0, 
     c} + {Cos[t], Sin[t]} . {(p1 - {0, 0, c}), p2 - {0, 0, c}} /. sol;
With[{p1 = p1, p2 = p2, p3 = p3, p4 = p4, circle = circle}, 
 Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[{Pyramid[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}] /. sol // Evaluate, 
    Opacity[.2], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 3], 
    ParametricPlot3D[circle, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive@{Thick, Opacity[1], Red}][[1]]}, 
   Boxed -> False], {l, 3, 3 Sqrt[3]}]]


