How to quickly find the volume and surface area of a spatial geometric solid with edge lengths containing parameters?
The coordinates of the vertices of a regular tetrahedron with edge length n are:
$Assumptions = n > 0;
pts = {a, b, c, d} = 
  n/Sqrt[8] {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}}

None of the following methods can be used to determine the volume and surface area.

Volume[ConvexHullRegion[{a, b, c, d}]] // Simplify


SurfaceArea[ConvexHullRegion[{a, b, c, d}]] // Simplify

How to quickly find the volume and surface area of a spatial geometric solid with edge lengths containing parameters?
$Assumptions = n > 0;
pts = {a, b, c, d} = 
  n/Sqrt[8] {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}}
s = Area@Triangle@{a, b, c} // Simplify
h = Abs@(d - a) . Normalize[(a - b)\[Cross](a - c)] // Simplify
v = 1/3 s h

Of course, this method above is not generalizable.

Documentation suggests that a hexahedron requires 8 points for definition.

(-1) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/307251/dynamic-image-of-the-square-pyramids-inscribed-in-a-sphere-that-meet-the-criteri#comment752930_307251

Why not
Tetrahedron[pts] // Volume (*Abs[n]^3/(6 Sqrt[2])*)
SurfaceArea[ Tetrahedron[pts]] (*Sqrt[3] Sqrt[n^4]*)


$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

pts = n/Sqrt[8] {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}};

Volume
vol[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[
  Volume@ConvexHullRegion[pts /. n -> #] & /@ Range[5], n]

(* n^3/(6 Sqrt[2]) *)

Checking,
And @@ Table[vol[n] == Volume@ConvexHullRegion[pts], {n, 20}]

(* True *)

Surface area
surfArea[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[
  SurfaceArea@ConvexHullRegion[pts /. n -> #] & /@ Range[5], n]

(* Sqrt[3] n^2 *)

Checking,
And @@ Table[surfArea[n] == SurfaceArea@ConvexHullRegion[pts], {n, 20}]

(* True *)

